In which Purana is the story of Pandavas worshiping Shiva in Kedarnath?
We hear many legends about the Pandavas worshiping Shiva in Kedarnath for expiating the sin of killing many in the Mahabharata battle. There must be some Puranic basis for this. The reference is required.

This is described in the Shiva Purana Kotirudra Samhita Chapter 19:

यो वै हि पाण्डवान्दृष्ट्वा माहिषं रूपमास्थितः ।
मायामास्थाय तत्रैव पलायनपरोऽभवत् ॥ १३ ॥

It was he who on seeing Pāṇḍavas assumed the form of a buffalo, having
recourse to his magical skill and began to run away.
धृतश्च पाण्डवैस्तत्र ह्यवाङ्मुखतया स्थितः ।
पुच्छ चैव धृतं तैस्तु प्रार्थितश्च पुनःपुनः ॥ १४ ॥

When he was caught by the Pāṇḍavas he stood with his face bent down.
They held his tail and implored him again and again.
तद्रूपेण स्थितस्तत्र भक्तवत्सलनामभाक् ।
नयपाले शिरोभागो गतस्तद्रूपतः स्थितः ॥ १५ ॥

He remained in that form in the name of Bhaktavatsala. His head
portion went and remained fixed in the city of Nayapāla. The lord
stood in that form there.
स वै व पूजनान्नित्यमाज्ञां चैवाप्यदात्तथा ।
पूजितश्च स्वयं शंभुस्तत्र तस्थौ वरानदात् ॥ १६ ॥

He asked them to worship him in that trunkless form. Worshipped by
them, Śiva remained there and granted boons.
पूजयित्वा गतास्ते तु पाण्डवा मुदितास्तदा ।
लब्ध्वा चित्तेप्सितं सर्वं विमुक्तास्सर्वदुःखतः ॥ १७ ॥

The Pāṇḍavas went away with joy after worshipping him. After obtaining
what they desired in their minds, they were rid of all their miseries.
तत्र नित्यं हस्साक्षात्क्षेत्रे केदारसंज्ञके ।
भारतीभिः प्रजाभिश्च तथेव परिपूज्यते ॥ १८ ॥

There in the shrine of Kedāra, Śiva is directly worshipped by the
people of Bhārata.


Thanks very much for the reply and reference from the Shiva Purana. Is there any image of the Pandavas in the Kedarnath temple?
